# How can I automate assigning locations (column D) in a matrix while optimizing the total distance (in cell E18)?

Tags: excel, matrix, optimization, automation

I am trying to assign a list of candidates (column B) to certain locations (row 3) based on the distance between their home and the location address. I have already calculated the distance between all the locations using a custom VBA formula. My challenge is, how do I ensure everyone is assigned to the most optimal location so we end up with the lowest possible total average distance (cell E18). I would also like to ensure nobody is assigned to a location more than 40miles from their house, where possible.

Here is my matrix, before locations assigned

[image]

I normally do this assignment step manually just plugging in different location assignments until I get something reasonable. However, there are times where we have 150+ candidates and 150+ locations which makes this extremely difficult and time-consuming. I'm looking for a way to automatically find the most ideal location assignments based on the total average distance.

is my matrix, after manually assigning locations

[image]

I normally do this assignment step manually and just plug in different location assignments until I get something reasonable. Sometimes I go by the techs with the least amount of viable location options first (so a tech with mostly longer distances) or sometimes I go with the locations with the least amount of viable candidates. This is fine when I have a small data set like this one. However, there are times when we have 150+ candidates and 150+ locations which makes this extremely difficult and time-consuming. I'm looking for a way to automatically find the most ideal location assignments based on the total average distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question boils down to "What numbers should I put in D4:D16, to get the minimum value in E18?" You can use the Excel Solver add-in for this.

File > Options > Add-ins > Manage Excel Add-ins > Go... > enable Solver Add-In > OK. Now on the Data tab you should see a Analyze tab with the Solver add-in.

Start by assigning random areas to each candidate, just give them 1-13.

Your Distance formula in E4 should be:

```
=INDEX($H$4:$T$16,MATCH(B4,$B$4:$B$16,0),MATCH(D4,$H$2:$T$2,0))
```

and you can drag that down as far as you need, but you will have to adjust it if you change the number of Candidates / Areas.

Open the Excel Solver and use the following parameters:

- Set Objective E18
- to Min
- By Changing Variable Cells: D4:D16
- Subject to the Constraints: (Click Add)
- D4:D16 = AllDifferent
- Select a Solving Method: Evolutionary
- (Click Solve)

Excel will start looping through all the possibilities. With the default settings, it will stop if it hasn't made any improvement in 30 seconds. This may not be the absolute best, but it will be very very good. You can do a search for Excel Solver if you do want to play with the settings.

[image]

Comment: Kevin, my man!! This is the solution I've been looking for! Thank you so much for the detailed walkthrough, you've helped me immensely.